# How do I install Django on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: python, django, installation

I'm using [The Definitive guide to installing Django on ubuntu](http://felecan.com/2011/definitive-guide-installing-django-ubuntu/) and ironically need something more definitive because I can't make it work.

(I have followed the steps before this on the link above)

Here is my situation/standstill:

```
drewverlee@ubuntu:/var/src$ tar xzvf Django-1.3.1.tar.gz
tar (child): Django-1.3.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So it tells me there is no file Django-1.3.1.tar.gz? I think I can check for a file by us by:

```
drewverlee@ubuntu:/var/src$ ls
index.html  index.html.1
drewverlee@ubuntu:/var/src$
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: you can use `pip` to install the most up to date version of django.  if you don't have `pip` you can issue `easy_install pip`.  Then type `pip install django`  This will automatically link django-admin.py for you and overall simplify the installation process.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm constantly amazed how many ways there are to tie my shoes..

Comment: Nominating for Reopen... The "tools commonly used by programmers" is worthless criteria and includes nearly everything. As such, Package Managers and Django is just as on topic as Apache and Nginx configurations and any other command or program on a distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, following the link I get the same problem, first.

```
mv index.html Django-1.3.1.tar.gz
```

fixes it for me. Then you can continue with

```
tar xzvf Django-1.3.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 17):

`pip` is best tool for installing python packages. Here is [link](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/) to install setup-tools and pip on ubuntu.

If you have installed pip then it will be very easy to install django and other python packages.

```
$ sudo pip install django
```

or for a specific version of django

```
$ sudo pip install django==1.3.1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ubuntu, then you can just use the package provided in the repositories:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-django
...
$ python -c 'import django; print django.get_version()'
1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Any guide that doesn't include virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper isn't definite enough for me :) Seriously, it will save you from a world of pain.

Also nginx + gunicorn now seems to be the default method for serving up django rather then Apache + mod_wsgi, but I'd say that that's less definite.

Answer (score 0):

1) download Django-1.3.1.tar.gz
https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

2) go into directory with the file

```
tar xzvf Django-1.3.1.tar.gz
cd Django-1.3.1
sudo python setup.py install
```

3) check if python sees django

```
>>> python
>>>import django
>>>print django.get_version()
```

After that you get Aptana as IDE to work with django

Answer (score 0):

if you have easy_install:

```
easy_install django
```

and for a specific version:

```
easy_install django==1.#.#
```